# How to convert session cookies between IE, chrome and firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, activex, microsoft-edge

I am able auto login into a site from my app using IE control. Now I need to pass on this session information to another browser like chrome or firefox.

What are the differences in the way IE, chrome and firefox store their cookies?

Comment: There is no trivial way to do this, send the other browser to a page passing the session id and any other cookie data as a query string then use whatever is on your server side to restore the session by setting the correct cookies in the response.

Comment: What scenario has your user changing their browser mid-session?

Comment: @Sampson Scenario when users have Chrome or Firefox as their default browser. The only way we know to auto login is using [IE WebBrowser ActiveX control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752040(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @SIDdeveloper You should find a different way to log your users in; Microsoft is dropping support for all versions of IE prior to 11, and IE 11 users are quickly moving to Edge, which doesn't support ActiveX.